# How to delete/select interior faces with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, retopology

Fairly basic question: is there a way to replicate the behaviour of the `Edit Mode` tool: `Select > Select All By Trait > Interior Faces` with Geonodes?

Comment: Probably too late now, but the solution has been made in a different question:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/302578/181620