# GeoNodes : How to delete interiors faces after voxelisation?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

i try to put my hand and brain into geometry node.
i voxelized an objet with:
Mesh to volume /
Distribute points to volume (grid) /
Instance on points (cube) /
Realize instances /
Merge by distance

now im trying to delete all interior faces to keep only the "shell" and i stuck here :(

is there a way to avoid using the mesh boolean node? i tried that but the computational time increase !
and i would not computing my mesh and using the "traditional" Select all by trait /delete interior faces...

so i was thinking of using "neighbors" node but i cant avoid holes in my mesh

Someone to helpme please? thanks

[image: nodes tree]

[image: Holes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shoot those damn internal faces down!

[image]

[image]

Comment: WAWwwww !!!
thank you cowboy !